# Can't read in directory 0 php. Steam web Api

Tags: php, json, steam, inventory

Hello I am making a program that read's steam inventories. I am getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '0' (T_LNUMBER), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/runner/SteamTradingTies/index.php on line 59
```

Is this an issue with Steam's API or with PHP?
Does anyone know how to fix this?

This is my code:

```
<?
$data = file_get_contents("https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/" . $steamprofile['steamid'] .    "/252490/2?count=5000");
$decodedData = json_decode($data);

echo $decodedData->descriptions->0->name;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `$decodedData->descriptions` is an array; try accessing the first element of that array with square brackets: `$decodedData->descriptions[0]->name;`

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it!